# Regex not matching

Tags: regex, scala

I expect regex `"[a-zA-Z]\\d{6}"` to match `"z999999"` but it is not matching as an empty List is mapped :

```
val lines = List("z999999");                      //> lines  : List[String] = List(z999999)

val regex = """[a-zA-Z]\d{6}""".r                 //> regex  : scala.util.matching.Regex = [a-zA-Z]\d{6}

val fi = lines.map(line => line match { case regex(group) => group case _ => "" })
                                                  //> fi  : List[String] = List("")
```

Is there a problem with my regex or how I'm using it with Scala ?

Comment: @Avinash Raj thanks, but same result

Comment: @AvinashRaj ive updated to match your suggestion but same result

Comment: You don't need that `;` after `List("z999999")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val l="z999999"
val regex = """[a-zA-Z]\d{6}""".r

regex.findAllIn(l).toList
res1: List[String] = List(z999999)
```

The regex seems valid.

```
lines.map( _ match { case regex(group) => group; case _ => "" })
res2: List[String] = List("")
```

How odd. Let's see what happens with a capturing group around the whole expression we defined in `regex`.

```
val regex2= """([a-zA-Z]\d{6})""".r
regex2: scala.util.matching.Regex = ([a-zA-Z]\d{6})
lines.map( _ match { case regex2(group) => group; case _ => "" })
res3: List[String] = List(z999999)
```

Huzzah.

The unapply method on a regex is for getting the results of capturing groups.

There are other methods on a regex object that just get matches (e.g. findAllIn, findFirstIn, etc)